# How to programmatically hide header and tabs in landscape mode in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have one view in portrait mode and another in landscape mode where I want to show chart and I hide tabs and header (fullscreen mode, no scrolling). My view in landscape mode would look something like this:

```
<div showWhen="landscape" class="chart-settings split-container">
<ion-toolbar showWhen="landscape">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Period</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="period">
            //options
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Won/Lost</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
             //options
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-toolbar>
<div class="flexChart">
  <div id="chartdiv" [style.width.%]="100" [style.height.%]="100"></div>
</div>
```

I use flex to fill out the page and create "fullscreen effect with no scrolling".

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well it seems there is this:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/

It has:

```
isPortrait()
isLandscape()
```

so you can do:
`platform.isPortrait()` or `platform.isLandscape()`
if you inject platform into constructor.

Combine this with `*NgIf`:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif

CSS overflow, `overflow-x`, `overflow-y` is what you'd look to for prevent scrolling provided it's a block level container:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

**UPDATE**

Based on this comment:

> That was my initial thought. The problem with this is that **it leaves
>   padding on top**. I solved it by configuring styles, but it seemed
>   pretty dirty solution to me

You can fix that padding issue by getting the instance of the `Content` and call the `resize()` method like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  public yourMethod(): void {
    this.content.resize();
  }
}
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#resize

> Tell the content to recalculate its dimensions. This should be called
>   after dynamically adding/removing headers, footers, or tabs.

Comment: That was my initial thought. The problem with this is that it leaves padding on top. I solved it by configuring styles, but it seemed pretty dirty solution to me.

Comment: I've made an edit to your post, to include how to fix that padding issue that the user mentioned. Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check landscape or portrait with platform, then you can get the ref of nav from template:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar #navBar>
    ...
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

and call `setHidden(true)` in component with its ref:

```
@ViewChild('navBar') navBar: Navbar
// call in proper place
this.navBar.setHidden(true)
```

for tabs, I think you can do in the same way